# how to disable jupyter editor in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

like the title mentioned, how to disable jupyter editor in vscode?
every time,I want to new a file just for text or markdown,I do not like to appear a choice between two, but just default for the inner editor applied by vscode. and how can I configure this.
for right now,I never need to use jupyter notebook.
It seems to be appeared unexpected after vscode update or installed some python package.

Comment: I don't know whether there is a setting to disable the notebook editor. You could disable the python extension all together if you don't need it. Still, vscode should not automatically open the notebook editor unless you create a new notebook (.ipynb) or open one. If you create or open a markdown / text file, it should open the regular editor.

Comment: "disable the python extension all together",I need these extensions for AI task, but I don't need notebook, I'm a programer that I use python native but not jupyter.

Comment: Well normally the notebook editor is linked to the `.ipynb` extension. If you open "normal" `.py` files, vscode should open the normal editor.

Comment: This case it's about new a file, not open a file.To new a file in vscode we get no suffix for the file.Usually,I new a file for saving it to text, markdown or python file.

Comment: In VS Code, couldn't one simply right-click and hit `Disable` on the Jupyter extension, and be done with it? Would this have some detrimental effect on basic Python usage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be disabled by `python.dataScience.useNotebookEditor` if you are using the Python extension.

Source: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/103526

**Update:**

You also need the [Jupyter extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-toolsai.jupyter) along with Python extension for VS Code. The setting key has been renamed from `python.dataScience.useNotebookEditor` to `jupyter.useNotebookEditor`[^update](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/python/introducing-the-jupyter-extension-for-vs-code/)

Comment: That issue was opened by me. :)

Answer (score 4):

With the July/August 2021 introduction of the new [Native Notebook Support in VS Code](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/wiki/Native-Notebook-Support-in-VS-Code#enabling-the-new-experience), the answers involving your `settings.json` are now  obsolete. Now the Notebook editor will be used to open `.*ipynb` files even if you've never installed the Python or Jupyter extensions.

However, you can open a `*.ipynb` file in the regular text editor by **right-clicking** on the file in the VS Code File Explorer, doing "**Open With**", and then selecting the "**Text Editor**".

Comment: `"workbench.editorAssociations": {*.ipynb": "default"}` in `settings.json`

Comment: @BGabor Changing the `workbench.editorAssociations` worked! Thank you very much for sharing. Just a minor typo fix - your `*.ipynb` is missing an opening double quote. I've added an opening double quote: `"workbench.editorAssociations": {"*.ipynb": "default"}`.